# ContextualVersionConflict for ctgansyntesizer (incopatible urllib3 version)

Tags: google-colaboratory, urllib3, botocore, sdv

So I'm working with `sdv` library on google collab for produsing synthetic data. When I use `ctgan` synthesizer I have this error:

> "ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 2.0.4
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages),
> Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4'), {'botocore'})"

It tells me that I have `urllib3` version 2.0.4 but i use 1.25.8 which is supposed to be compatible

Below is the output of sdv installation:

> "Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from botocore<2,>=1.18->sdv)
> (1.25.8) "

Also when I run `pip show urllib3` it shows the right version 1.25.8

Why it tells me that I use 2.0.4 version?